# Why does the integral for this function not exist

Tags: indefinite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to integrate this function on Wolfram Alpha, but it says "no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions".

$$\frac{\alpha t^{\alpha-1}e^{-(t/\beta)^\alpha}}{\beta^\alpha}$$

However, if I just substitute $u$ for $-(t/\beta)^\alpha$, I'd get the integral as $-e^{-(t/\beta)^\alpha} + C$.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Could the community please help me figure out my mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: You **may** have mistakenly inserted $t^{\alpha -1}(e^{-(t/\beta)})^\alpha$ instead of $ t^{\alpha -1}e^{-(t/\beta)^\alpha}$ in Wolfram calculator?

Comment: $$ \frac{ \alpha t^{\alpha -1} e^{-(t/\beta)^\alpha}} {\beta^\alpha} \, dt \quad=\quad \alpha \left( \frac t \beta \right)^{\alpha-1} e^{-(t/\beta)^\alpha}\, \left( \frac{dt}\beta \right) \quad=\quad \alpha s^{\alpha-1} e^{-s^\alpha}\, ds $$ So the parameter $\beta$ seems for present purposes to be clutter, better dispensed with by this substitution. $\qquad$

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar : If that mistake were made, I'd expect Wolfram to give a closed-form answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = (t/\beta)^\alpha.$ Then $du = \alpha(t/\beta)^{\alpha-1}(dt/\beta).$ Therefore
$$
\int \frac{ \alpha t^{\alpha -1} e^{-(t/\beta)^\alpha}} {\beta^\alpha} \, dt = \int \alpha \left( \frac t \beta \right)^{\alpha-1} e^{-(t/\beta)^\alpha} \left( \frac {dt} \beta\right) = \int e^{-u^\alpha} \, du.
$$
In any course on theory of probability you hear that this has no closed form when $\alpha = 2.$ I would guess it has a closed form only for special values of $\alpha,$ perhaps only for $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=1.$

Comment: Wouldn't the final functional form be $\int e^{-u} \, du$

Comment: I'm confused. The derivative of $-\exp (-(t/b)^a)$ is $a t^{a-1}b^{-a}\exp (-(t/b)^a)$  exactly as in the Q.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : Except that you've got one too many minus signs. But why is that an occasion for confusion?